# Javascript Form Submit causing website to break

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

So I'm having an issue submitting a form.  Basically once the form is submitted the entire site wont work until I clear the cash and refresh the browser.

The form tag is 
`<form action="cart.php" method="post" name="AutomaticReorderForm">`

The form was initially being submitted like

```
function saveAutomaticReorder()
{
document.AutomaticReorderForm.action = "/store/save_automatic_order.php";
document.AutomaticReorderForm.submit();
}
```

which has a javascript call to this function in the href of the button.

I tried jquery like so

```
$("#saveAutomaticReorder").click(function() {
    $('form[name="AutomaticReorderForm"]').attr("action", "/store/save_automatic_order.php");
    $('form[name="AutomaticReorderForm"]').submit();
});
```

These both submit the form fine.  In the php page at the very top i put in `die();` which killed the page before any php was run but then it still gave me the same problem of breaking the whole site.  Im not sure where to go from here does anyone have an idea about what could be causing this issue?  Thanks

Comment: What is exactly what happens when you submit?

Comment: This could be unrelated, but your code is missing the closing quotes on your attr selector: `$('form[name="AutomaticReorderForm')` should be `$('form[name="AutomaticReorderForm"')`.

Comment: When I submit it currently is going to the php page where I am running die() so it just sits there, but the whole site is still broken until I refresh and clear cache!

Comment: Nothing gets outputed after a die as the script exits. If you need the other parts of your site to be outputed don't exit

Comment: When you submit and you are using die(); you will see a blank page, so what is you trying to say with "broken"?

Comment: what do u mean by breaking the website

Comment: If I let it fully render I still get the same problem.  My only point about the die was that it wasnt the php script that is breaking the site.  Neither is it breaking from going to the page where the form is.  So somehow by submitting the form everything is just going white and the source of all the pages are blank until I refresh.

Comment: You are using cookies, session and includes i guess.

Comment: Correct, it must be somewhere in there

Comment: Off-topic: You should use `document.forms.AutomaticReorderForm` instead of `document.AutomaticReorderForm`

Comment: So your are setting a session variable somewhere where the script is throwing and error or die()

Comment: Yeah, it gets pretty complex and its only happening on our production site.  So, Im just going to get the contractor who designed it to figure it out.  Thanks though.